# php curl mock curl --data-binary

Tags: php, curl

`curl --data-binary "{\"userid\":1234,\"friendlist\":[111,80010,80029,804189]}" "http://someurl.org/getuserinfo?appid=15&token=1382410267"`

Is it possible to execute this using php curl extension?

```
curl_setopt($this->_ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($this->_ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($this->_ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 2.5);


curl_setopt($this->_ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($this->_ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($this->_ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($postFields));
```

but doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER says no processing is done on what you get back, --data-binary says no processing is done on what you send out. If the command line works, increase the verbosity (-v) and compare with what you send in php (turn CURLOPT_HEADER and CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT on).